# Correct way to remove specific text from href value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

What's the correct way to remove specific text from href value.

Here is my code:

```
 <li  class="nav-item" data-attr="Some value"><a  class="nav-link scroll-to" href="porcupinev.com.au/visit#directions" data-attr="Some value">Getting Here</a></li>

<li  class="nav-item" data-attr="Some value"><a  class="nav-link scroll-to" href="porcupinev.com.au/visit#map" data-attr="Some value">Getting Here</a></li>
```

I need to remove 'porcupinev.com.au/visit' from each href so the # acts as an internal anchor without the prefix url

Using TWIG templating engine but no solution with that language so need jQuery solution

Answer (score 1):

First define prefix that needs replacing:

```
const prefix='porcupinev.com.au/visit'
```

Then find all `A` elements starting with prefix.

```
$('a[href^="' + prefix + '"]')
```

and iterate over each one updating the `href` attribute:

```
$('a[href^="' + prefix + '"]').each(
    (ind, el) => $(el).attr('href', $(el).attr('href').replace(prefix, ''))
)
```

**Updated:** Here's full code:

```html
<li class="nav-item" data-attr="Some value"><a class="nav-link scroll-to" href="porcupinev.com.au/visit#directions"
        data-attr="Some value">Getting Here</a></li>

<li class="nav-item" data-attr="Some value"><a class="nav-link scroll-to" href="porcupinev.com.au/visit#map"
        data-attr="Some value">Getting Here</a></li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(() => {
        const prefix = 'porcupinev.com.au/visit'
        $('a[href^="' + prefix + '"]').each(
            (ind, el) => $(el).attr('href', $(el).attr('href').replace(prefix, ''))
        )
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry bit of a newly, what would that look like in a full script?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your question